# display module in mobile version of theme prestashop 1.7

Tags: position, hook, display, prestashop-1.7

I use [madina](http://madina.demo.towerthemes.com/) theme and I have made some changes on header,

I have changed the hook of slideshow module to move it right to menu

therefore slideshow module won't appear in mobile version of theme

how can I display it in mobile version before newer products

here is what I have now : [beta website](http://bricosg.cluster026.hosting.ovh.net/bs1)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have module enabled on mobile. Go to your Modules list in back office, search for this slider module, click this selectbox wehere you have "Configure" button, and check if you have "Disable on mobile" or "Enable on mobile"

Comment: I don't have this checkbox in configuration page of module

Comment: No, no, you don't need to go to the Configuration page, you need check options in your selectbox list, there you should have an option to disable or enable module on mobile, everything is available from the module list, not a module configuration page